# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `style` of type `number` supplied to `Styled(Container)`, expected `object`

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm just getting this warning which is filling up my console:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `style` of type `number` supplied to `Styled(Container)`, expected `object`.
    in Styled(Container) (created by SearchPage)
    in SearchPage (created by Connect(SearchPage))
    in Connect(SearchPage) (created by Vepo)
    in Vepo (created by App)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

Here is the code in question:

**SearchPage.js**

```
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import {
  Container,
  Button,
  Text,
  Header,
  Body,
  Right,
  Left,
  Title
} from 'native-base'
import React from 'react'
import Keywords from '../keywords/Keywords'
import Categories from '../categories/Categories'
import Location from '../location/Location'
import Map from '../map/Map'
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleMenu } from './searchPage.action'
import { styles } from '../../style'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isMenuOpen: state.get('searchPage').get('isMenuOpen')
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  toggleMenu: () => {
    dispatch(toggleMenu())
  }
})

let SearchPage = (props) => {
  const menu = (
    <Container>
      <Header style={styles.header}>
        <Left>
          <Button transparent>
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title style={styles.title}>Search</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right>
        </Right>
      </Header>
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView >
          <Categories />
          <Location />
          <Keywords />
          <Button block style={styles.wideButton} onPress={() => props.toggleMenu()}><Text>GO</Text></Button>
        </ScrollView>
      </Container>
    </Container>
  )
  return (
    <Drawer
      open={props.isMenuOpen}
      content={menu}
    >
      <Container style={mapStyles.container}>
        <Map />
      </Container>

    </Drawer>
  )
}
SearchPage.propTypes = {
  toggleMenu: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isMenuOpen: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

SearchPage = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SearchPage)

export default SearchPage

const mapStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
})
```

The answers to this question online seem to be to use a plain object rather than `Stylesheet.create()`. However, the styling gets completely messed up when I do so.

How do I get rid of the annoying warning?

contents of `../../style` file from above code:

**style.js**

```
const $mainColor = '#EFEFEF'
export const styles = {
  list: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: 8
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: $mainColor,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  wideButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#FF3B3F',
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 1
    },
    shadowRadius: 1,
    shadowOpacity: 1.0
  },
  label: {
    color: '#9E9E9E',
    fontWeight: '200'
  },
  formItem: {
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  icon: {
    width: 30
  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#F7F7F7'
  },
  arrow: {
    color: '#9E9E9E'
  },
  modalView: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: 8
  },
  modal: {
    height: 100
  },
  title: {
    color: '#9E9E9E',
    fontWeight: '200'
  },
}
```

Comment: Could you post your Styled component too?

Comment: @Shota I think it is posted - the `<Container style={mapStyles.container}>`

Comment: Looks like the part of code that causes this issue is not posted here. From warning message, you can see that Styled component is doing prop validation of "style" prop as a number, while you are passing an object.

Comment: @Shota it says it is created by `SearchPage`, so I posted the whole `SearchPage`. Doesn't it mean the issue is in `SearchPage`?

Comment: The key here is "supplied to `Styled(Container)`" which means you are passing the incorrect props to `Styled` component.

Comment: @Shota I don't have a component called `Styled` so I cannot think of what component the issue could be in.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the `../../style` file in your question? I think the error is at the line `<Container style={styles.container}>`, so perhaps `styles.container` is a string?

Comment: @ArneHugo Yes just posted it thanks. `styles.container` is an object, unfortunately. Let me know if you see something wrong with it :)

Comment: @Shota `Styled(Container)` is imported as `Container` from [native-base's Container.js](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/031cd958b51a043480f3cc4b665a05640654545d/src/basic/Container.js)

Answer (score 8):

I got the similar problem and i just solved it!

I am using the react-native-swiper in my ios app and when i tried to style the `<Swiper>`, i got the same problem as you are:

```
Warning:Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'dotStyle' of type 'number' supplied to '_class', expected 'object';
```

here is my code: (you can just focus on the `<Swiper>` and its dotStyle

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
View,
Text,
StyleSheet,
Image,
} from 'react-native'

import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
bannerItem: {
    width:405,
    height:240,
},
dotStyle: {
    width:10,
    height:10,
    borderRadius:5,
},
activeDotStyle: {
    width:10,
    height:10,
    borderRadius:5,
},
});
```

And

```
export default class Banner extends Component {
render() {
    return (
    <View>
        <Swiper style={styles.wrapper}
        autoplay={true}
        height={240} 
        activeDotColor="orange"
        dotStyle={styles.dotStyle}  //Warning happens here
        >
      <View>
        <Image style={styles.bannerItem} source={require('../img/carousel1.jpg')}/>
     </View>
      <View>
        <Image style={styles.bannerItem} source={require('../img/carousel3.jpg')}/>
       </View>
      <View>
        <Image style={styles.bannerItem} source=
{require('../img/carousel4.jpg')}/>
       </View>
      </Swiper>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

And it shocked me when i write css object directle in `<Swiper>`, it work:

```
dotStyle={{
    width:10,
    height:10,
    borderRadius:5,
}}
```

it turns back a number (styleId) instead of a object, just like what the warning describe.

but i don't like write css object directly in jsx, so i use `flatten()`

this method renturns a object

here's the docs:

> StyleSheet.flatten(styles.listItem); // return { flex: 1, fontSize: 16, color: 'white' } // Simply styles.listItem would return its ID (number)
>
> This method internally uses StyleSheetRegistry.getStyleByID(style) to resolve style objects represented by IDs.
>
> Thus, an array of style objects (instances of StyleSheet.create), are individually resolved to, their respective objects, merged as one and then returned.

[offical doc about StyleSheet(in the bottom)](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.46/docs/stylesheet.html#stylesheet)

so i rewrite like this in jsx

`dotStyle={StyleSheet.flatten(styles.dotStyle)}`

and it work.

hope it can help(￣▽￣)~*

Answer (score 2):

prop named style is passed to a component named Container.
Container requires prop style to be an object but its been passed as number.

So just try the below flatten method to provide appropriate prop type.

```
StyleSheet.flatten(mapStyles.container)
```

let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work. But it might be because I create `mapStyles` and I also import `styles`?

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins I don't think that should be a problem.

Comment: I was trying get something from the docs http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/stylesheet.html#flatten
Also from there I found one more thing i.e. use StyleSheetRegistry.getStyleByID(style) where style is the id in number format. This method is used internally to resolve style objects represented by IDs.

Comment: @Shahzad: I see. In that case a fix to @BeniaminoBaggins' problem could be to just drop `StyleSheet.create(obj)` and just do `const style = obj`. In either case, you seem to have found the cause of the problem. I suggest adding this explanation to your answer as well.

Comment: @ArneHugo using a plain object instead of `Stylesheet.create()` breaks the styling.

Comment: @Shahzad Thanks. I can't find an example of how to register the stylesheet with an id and then get the stylesheet by id.

Comment: This was very helpful for DrowdownAlert stying of titleStyle and messageStyle.
Ex: `messageStyle={StyleSheet.flatten(styles._myAlertMessageStyle)}`.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to use NativeBase screen structure is to have all the components within

```
<Container>
```

like below.

```
 <Container>
    <Header>
        <Left>
            <Button transparent>
                <Icon name='menu' />
            </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
            <Title>Header</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right />
    </Header>
    <Content>
        // Your main content goes here
    </Content>
    <Footer>
        <FooterTab>
            <Button full>
                <Text>Footer</Text>
            </Button>
        </FooterTab>
    </Footer>
</Container>
```

and it won't support style prop. so you are getting warning. 
please update your code and remove style attribute in container component.

Comment: Thanks. How do we style the container? We cannot? Is the workaround to style the elements inside the container instead?

Comment: You have apply styles only child components not container component.

Comment: "How do we style the container? " .. Here: [use nativebase themes](http://rawgit.com/GeekyAnts/native-base-docs/v2.2/_book/Customize.html#theaming-nb-headref)

Comment: Container is not real react component so if you want custom view then you can build custom theme. http://rawgit.com/GeekyAnts/native-base-docs/v2.2/_book/Customize.html#Customize